# How to debug external display connectivity problems?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, vga

I'm having problems with connecting my retina MBP with external displays of all kinds. The DisplayPort->VGA adapter has a 1/4 success rate. The HDMI port (via a DVI adapter) does not see my monitor.

These monitors all work with every other laptop (Mac, Windows and Linux), including my old pre-unibody MBP. Worst of all, I cannot depend on this laptop to make presentations, because it's often failed to connect to projectors.

How can I debug these problems? I don't see any obvious way to resolve issues when automatic discovery fails.

Comment: Has it ever worked in the past or did you have these problem right out of the gate when getting the machine? If it hasn't worked at all, it's probably a hardware issue.

Comment: It's worked with some monitors, just not the majority.

Comment: But the question stands, is there a way to debug/get error messages/try manually? Or is the automatic system the only way?